# What other things i need to complie python2.7.5 from source on commandline

Tags: python, webserver, centos, mod-wsgi

I want to compile python2.7.5 from source. Initially i ran into too many troubles. and people say i had to use this option or that option while compiling. I also need to use `django` with `mod_wsgi` So i know i need to use this option

```
./configure --enable-shared
make
make install
```

i want to know that is there any other option which i can add so that i don't need to recompile it. As longs as it does not harm i am ready to install everything but i just want to know main things which are not avaialble by default but we may need those

I will be basically using `Django , webserver with apache , nginx etc for web site hosting or postgresql etc`. CentOS 6.4 OS

EDIT:
Comon guys anyone should have told me `--with-ssl` . It wasted my 10 hours

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @user1958218: Doesn't Centos come with a package manager? Why do you want to compile from source?

Comment: @Blender  because it does not use --enable-shared which i need for mod_wsgi